# jquery ajax form success callback not being called

Tags: jquery, django, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using "AJAX", process data in the file and then return some of that data to the UI so I can dynamically update the screen.

I'm using the JQuery Ajax Form Plugin, jquery.form.js found at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ for the javascript and using Django on the back end. The form is being submitted and the processing on the back end is going through without a problem, but when a response is received from the server, my Firefox browser prompts me to download/open a file of type "application/json". The file has the json content that I've been trying to send to the browser.

I don't believe this is an issue with how I'm sending the json as I have a modularized `json_wrapper()` function that I'm using in multiple places in this same application.

Here is what my form looks after Django templates are applied:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/test_suites/active/upload_results/805/">
  <p>
     <label for="id_resultfile">Upload File:</label> 
     <input type="file" id="id_resultfile" name="resultfile">
  </p>  
</form>
```

You won't see any submit buttons because I'm calling submit with a button else where and am using ajaxSubmit() from the jquery.form.js plugin.

Here is the controlling javascript code:

```
function upload_results($dialog_box){
    $form = $dialog_box.find("form");
    var options = {
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                alert("Hello!!");
            },
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                console.log("errors");

            },
            beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options){
                    console.log(formData, jqForm, options);
                },
        }
    $form.submit(function(){
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
    $form.ajaxSubmit(options);
}
```

As you can see, I've gotten desperate to see the success callback function work and simply have an alert message created on success. However, we never reach that call. Also, the `error` function is not called and the `beforeSubmit` function is executed.

The file that I get back has the following contents:

```
{"count": 18, "failed": 0, "completed": 18, "success": true, "trasaction_id": "SQEID0.231"}
```

I use 'success' here to denote whether or not the server was able to run the post command adequately. If it failed the result would look something like:

```
{"success": false, "message":"<error_message>"}
```

Your time and help is greatly appreciated. I've spent a few days on this now and would love to move on.

Comment: Does the `error` call execute? or the `beforeSubmit`?  Checking the actual response in firebug or chrome would help as well, to see what's actually coming back.

Comment: No, the error call doesn't execute but the beforeSubmit does. We also know everything is working fine before submit, since the server side processing is running properly.

Comment: @Michael - What response are you seeing in the firebug/chrome/fidler net panel?

Comment: @Nick - [Object { name="resultfile",  more...}] [form /test_su...lts/805/] Object { url="/test_suites/active/upload_results/805/",  more...} Each of those elements are toggleable (I'm using Firebug btw) Oh and for clarification, all of the code above was essentially coded from scratch. There is no cut and paste, just in case that was a concern.

Comment: @Michael - Can you post complete response in your question?  That doesn't appear to be valid JSON, which would cause the parser to fail.

Comment: @Nick - The reason the console doesn't seem to have proper JSON is probably because it's not Javascript encoded when being displayed. I'm assuming that firebug is storing these objects off and displaying their information in a relatively easy to read notation.

Comment: @Michael - your response looks good, any chance you have a link to a page I can see?

Comment: @Nick - unfortunately, I don't. This is an internal project for work, and I don't have any readily available environment to host something on. Any other ideas? Thanks for trying so far

Comment: @Michael - sorry, I'm not sure what else to try without seeing the page, the response is *exactly* what you posted, nothing around it or anything?

Comment: @Nick - No, nothing else seems to be around it. I believe in the past when a parser would fail, the function call failed. Here, it's being treated as a downloadable. So, I don't think it's a parsing problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone had a similar problem, here's the final javascript I ended up using:

```
function upload_results_dialog($data_elem){
    var $dialog_box = $("#ajax-dialog-box"),
    data = $data_elem.attr("data");
    $.ajax({
        url: "../upload/" + data+ "/",
        success: function(response){
            $dialog_box.html(response);
            $dialog_box.dialog("option",
                {
                    title: "Upload",
                    height: 260,
                    width: 450,
                    buttons: {
                        Cancel: function(){
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        Upload: function(){
                            upload($(this));
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
            $dialog_box.dialog('open');
        }
    });
}
function upload($dialog_box){
    var $form = $dialog_box.find("form"),
      iframe = $dialog_box.find("iframe"),
      $html = $($iframe.contents()),
      $iframe_form = $html.find("form");
    $iframe_form.html($form.contents());

    //Set the onload function
    $iframe.attr("onload","check_file_uploaded_valid()");
    $iframe_form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I just spent hours with this same problem going through the js file line by line.  It was working one second and then the next it wasnt.  My problem was - I had deleted the target div for the results.  Once i put that back in, it worked fine.

Comment: I confirm this is true, fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me as well.  Problem turned out to be the server wasn't converting the entire object to proper JSON.  Changed the return value to only the properties I needed:

```
return Json(new {Id = group.Id, Name = group.Name});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$('#form-id').ajaxForm();` in the document ready jQuery event so the plugin registers all the event handlers.

Comment: from my understanding, the $form.ajaxSubmit() should be calling the event (by passing the need for event handlers).

Comment: If you call ajaxSubmit without ajaxForm on the target form, the handlers do not bind. I can tell this because I had this problem two days ago.